# Error creating Hibernate SessionFactory bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got this error when am trying to run the application, I think it is complaining about error creating sessionFactory and injection dependencies failed. I have been trying to fix it all day long. Thank you

This is the error ouput from the console.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.donah.web.dao.UserDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/donah/web/config/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.donah.web.dao.Users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.donah.web.dao.UserDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/donah/web/config/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.donah.web.dao.Users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/donah/web/config/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.donah.web.dao.Users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)!
```

This is the UserDao class

```
@Repository
@Component("userDao")
public class UserDao {

    public UserDao(){}

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void createUser(Users user) {
        session().save(user);
    }

    public Users getUser(String username) {

        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Users.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.idEq(username));
        return (Users) crit.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.donah.web.dao.Users

This is the cause of your problem. It means that the `Users` entity (btw, it is strange to have JPA entities in package called dao) has no identifier. It is mandatory that every JPA entity has an identifier.

Based on `Restrictions.idEq(username)` I guess that you use username as the primary key, so you should put [`@Id`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html) annotation on the username property in your `Users` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    private String username;

    // other properties and getters/setters
}
```

More details can be found for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm).